# Download APK from Google Play Console (beta)

Tags: google-play-console-beta

With the new Google Play console update, I can't seem to find the option to download an APK for a release. Has this been removed? I have tried to look over sub-menus but no success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this functionality has been introduced with the updated Play Console, but now I am able to download the APK:

App bundle explorer -> Downloads Tab

And at the bottom, you should have the original file.